# Combine / composite multiple video streams from appsrc

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I'm trying create a series of modules using gstreamer to do various tasks, so I can then just plug them into one another (I know that means it's a pipeline of pipelines, but it's what we've gone with). I have modules that read from file, read from a RTP stream, broadcast RTP, scale my video, change the framerate, change the rotation, and the one I'm working on combines multiple video streams (not looking at the audio yet) and produces a composite stream.

All my middle modules have the basic structure:
appsrc -> stuff -> appsink
With the starter and finisher modules using appsrc and appsink as needed.

For my compositor, the basic structure is that I create a vector of appsrc (well, a unique_ptr of a vector), link those to the compositor, then the compositor to the appsink via a capsfilter to set the width and height of the output stream.

I'm currently testing it with a series of media files I have locally on my machine. The problem I have is that if I set the appsrc `is-live` to `false` it works, right up until the first file finishes, at which point it freezes. According to https://gstreamer-devel.narkive.com/dwIsGwVZ/add-sink-pad-to-compositor-while-playing the issue is that with `is-live = false`, the compositor waits until it gets data on all of its pads before it does anything, which limits me to only compositing streams of the exact same length. However, if I set `is-live` to `true` then nothing works. I get lots of warnings about my appsrc dropping buffers:

```
WARN                  appsrc gstappsrc.c:2610:gst_app_src_push_internal:<multiplex_appsrc_1> Dropping old item buffer: 0x7fdbb806fea0, pts 0:00:05.416666666, dts 99:99:99.999999999, dur 0:00:00.041666666, size 194400, offset none, offset_end none, flags 0x0
```

I attach some of the code below to show how I'm creating and linking the pipeline. I think the problem comes from timestamps somehow, but setting `do-timestamp` makes no difference that I can see. Any suggestions would be welcome!

```
for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_inputs; ++i)
{
    string element_name = "multiplex_appsrc_" + std::to_string(i);

    _appsrcs->push_back(gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", element_name.c_str()));
}

_compositor = gst_element_factory_make("compositor", "multiplex_compositor");
_capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "multiplexer_capsfilter");
_appsink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "multiplex_appsink");
_bus = gst_element_get_bus(_pipeline);

for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_inputs; ++i)
{
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_appsrcs->at(i)), "block", true,
                 "stream-type", GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM,
                 "leaky-type", GST_APP_LEAKY_TYPE_DOWNSTREAM,
                 "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
                 //"do-timestamp", true,
                 "is-live", true, NULL);
}

g_object_set(_compositor, "background", 1,
             "ignore-inactive-pads", true, NULL);

_caps = // Set width and height of output according to some logic about number of inputs
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_capsfilter), "caps", _caps, NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_inputs; ++i)
{
    gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(_pipeline), _appsrcs->at(i));
}

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(_pipeline), _compositor, _capsfilter, _appsink, NULL);

if (! gst_element_link_many(_compositor, _capsfilter, _appsink, NULL))
{
    gst_object_unref(_pipeline);
    return;
}

// Try linking the on request pads
int total_number_of_columns = ceil(std::sqrt(_number_of_inputs));

for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_inputs; ++i)
{
    GstPad * compositor_pad = gst_element_request_pad_simple(_compositor, "sink_%u"); // Potential for memory leak? Do I need to unref this at some point?
    GstPad * appsrc_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(_appsrcs->at(i), "src");

    if (gst_pad_link(appsrc_pad, compositor_pad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    gst_object_unref(appsrc_pad);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In traditional style, the thing I attempted immediately after posting this question seems to resolve it. It runs, and the longer video seems to continue running after the shorter is finished. Will post again if it turns out to introduce side-effects, but the solution is to set the compositor to have some latency:

```
g_object_set(_compositor, "background", 1,
             "ignore-inactive-pads", true,
             "latency", 2000000000, NULL);
```

EDIT:
This worked on the Friday. I then came back in on Monday and it's stopped working. Your mileage may vary...